# Scala : Print List of List into a file : each nested list is a new line

Tags: scala, file, dictionary, foreach

Pretty New to Scala.
Trying this

```
val ListNew=List(List("this", "is", "it?"), List("yeah", "what", "else", "do","you","expect"))
```

into a File / Screen , like this:

```
this is it? \n
yeah what else do you expect
```

I did manage it with the following code

```
var ctr =0 ;
ListNew.map(k=>  for(rec <-k  ) {ctr=ctr+1 ;if (ctr == k.length){print(rec +"\n " );ctr =0; } else {print(rec+" ")}  })
```

But I dont want counters : Is there a way to get a print "\n" before two **foreach** .I tried Iterators , could not get them right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
println(ListNew.map(_.mkString(" ")).mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: Thank you very very much !!

Answer (score 2):

As you are new to scala this would be more useful

```
scala> val list = List(List("this", "is", "it?"), List("yeah", "what", "else", "do","you","expect"))
list: List[List[String]] = List(List(this, is, it?), List(yeah, what, else, do, you, expect))

scala> val sentenceList = list.map(x => x.mkString(" "))
sentenceList: List[String] = List(this is it?, yeah what else do you expect)

scala> sentenceList.mkString("\n")
res17: String =
this is it?
yeah what else do you expect
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListNew.foreach{ list => println(list.reduce(_ + " " +  _)) }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".